# React Create App -> Why SASS compiled css variables 2 time

Tags: css, sass, css-variables, create-react-app

React Create App 
Conflict with sass and css variables

React 16.7.0
node-sass ^4.13.0"
sass-loader ^8.0.0

------ SASS ------

```
:root {
  --ffRegular: "Cera-Regular";
  --color1: #{$color1};
  --color2: #{$color2};
  --color3: #{$color3};
}

body {
  font-family: var(--ffRegular);
  background: var(--color3);
  color: var(--color1);
}
```

---------- compiled css --------

```
body {
  font-family: "Cera-Regular";
  font-family: var(--ffRegular);
  background: #ffffff;
  background: var(--color3);
  color: #000000;
  color: var(--color1);
}
```

[On Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTbob.png)